# How to sort Javascript array of objects based on mapped keys between objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need to write a function that sorts this array based on dialog_node key and previous_sibling keys. The previous_sibling of the next object matches the dialog_node value of the previous object in the array. I don't need to keep the same logic in the function, this is just what I tried for sorting. The first item that should be at top of the list won't necessarily be at the beginning of the array.

```
export function orderDialogNodes(nodes) {
  // Create a mapping of dialog_node to its corresponding index in the array
  const nodeIndexMap = {};

  nodes.forEach((node, index) => {
    nodeIndexMap[node.dialog_node] = index;
  });

  // Sort the array based on the previous_sibling property
  nodes.sort((a, b) => {
    const indexA = nodeIndexMap[a.previous_sibling];
    const indexB = nodeIndexMap[b.previous_sibling];

    return indexA - indexB;
  });

  return nodes;
}

const inputArray = [
  {
    type: "folder",
    title: "Q&A Total Rewards",
    dialog_node: "node_2_1702794723026",
    previous_sibling: "node_1_1702793119621",
  },
  {
    type: "folder",
    title: "Q&A Payroll Taxes",
    dialog_node: "node_3_1702794877277",
    previous_sibling: "node_2_1702794723026",
  },
  {
    type: "folder",
    title: "Q&A Contacts",
    dialog_node: "node_1_1702793119621",
    previous_sibling: "node_10_1704313850082",
  },
  {
    type: "folder",
    title: "Feedback Capture Flow",
    dialog_node: "node_3_1702952290373",
    previous_sibling: "node_76_7439096406",
  },
  {
    type: "folder",
    title: "Q&A Benefits",
    dialog_node: "node_33_6664725040",
    previous_sibling: "node_3_1702794877277",
  },
  {
    type: "folder",
    title: "Q&A Perf Mgmt",
    dialog_node: "node_54_3521545375",
    previous_sibling: "node_33_6664725040",
  },
  {
    type: "folder",
    title: "Q&A Workday How To",
    dialog_node: "node_7_1702794820202",
    previous_sibling: "node_54_3521545375",
  },
  {
    type: "folder",
    title: "Q&A Learning",
    dialog_node: "node_7_1702794902054",
    previous_sibling: "node_7_1702794820202",
  },
  {
    type: "folder",
    title: "Q&A Levels",
    dialog_node: "node_76_7439096406",
    previous_sibling: "node_9_1702956631016",
  },
  {
    type: "folder",
    title: "Q&A Promo",
    dialog_node: "node_9_1702956631016",
    previous_sibling: "node_7_1702794902054",
  },
];

const orderedArray = orderDialogNodes(inputArray);
console.log(orderedArray);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't use `Array::sort()` here, since you can't directly compare non-siblings and the sort algorithm sometimes ask to compare non-siblings. The indices in the original array are also useless since they can be random.

So a more natural way would be a build a linked list and then convert it to an array:

```js
const list = {};
inputArray.forEach(item => {
  (list[item.dialog_node] ??= {}).item = item;
  const prev = list[item.previous_sibling];
  if(!prev){
    list[item.previous_sibling] = {next:list[item.dialog_node]};
  } else {
    prev.next = list[item.dialog_node];
  }
});
let head = Object.values(list).find(item => !item.item);
const result = [];
while(head = head.next) result.push(head.item);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>
const inputArray=[{type:"folder",title:"Q&A Total Rewards",dialog_node:"node_2_1702794723026",previous_sibling:"node_1_1702793119621"},{type:"folder",title:"Q&A Payroll Taxes",dialog_node:"node_3_1702794877277",previous_sibling:"node_2_1702794723026"},{type:"folder",title:"Q&A Contacts",dialog_node:"node_1_1702793119621",previous_sibling:"node_10_1704313850082"},{type:"folder",title:"Feedback Capture Flow",dialog_node:"node_3_1702952290373",previous_sibling:"node_76_7439096406"},{type:"folder",title:"Q&A Benefits",dialog_node:"node_33_6664725040",previous_sibling:"node_3_1702794877277"},{type:"folder",title:"Q&A Perf Mgmt",dialog_node:"node_54_3521545375",previous_sibling:"node_33_6664725040"},{type:"folder",title:"Q&A Workday How To",dialog_node:"node_7_1702794820202",previous_sibling:"node_54_3521545375"},{type:"folder",title:"Q&A Learning",dialog_node:"node_7_1702794902054",previous_sibling:"node_7_1702794820202"},{type:"folder",title:"Q&A Snap Levels",dialog_node:"node_76_7439096406",previous_sibling:"node_9_1702956631016"},{type:"folder",title:"Q&A Promo",dialog_node:"node_9_1702956631016",previous_sibling:"node_7_1702794902054"},];
</script>
```

**UPDATE** Initially I was intended to keep track of the list's head, but failed, so I find it after building a list. So now I've added tracking of all possible heads and find the head in this head list.
I've optimized the original to match the new version so no `Object.values()` is used to avoid an intermediate array. So keeping track of heads is noticeably faster. I've also tried a 2-way linked list, but the speed the same as with the tracking heads regardless of the input's size (which is strange, because time complexity is different).

```
` Chrome/121
-------------------------------------------------------
track heads   1.00x  |  x10000  396  401  403  413  427
find head     1.67x  |  x10000  660  667  682  690  702
-------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const inputArray=[];
let count = 1000;
let prev;
while(count--){
  const id = 'node_' + Math.random().toString().slice(2);
  prev = inputArray[inputArray.length] = {dialog_node:id, previous_sibling: prev?.dialog_node};
}

// @benchmark find head
{
const list = {};
inputArray.forEach(item => {
  const node = list[item.dialog_node] ??= {};
  node.item = item;
  (list[item.previous_sibling] ??= {}).next = node;
});
let head;
for(const k in list){
  if(!list[k].item){
    head = list[k];
    break;
  }
}
const result = [];
while(head = head.next) result.push(head.item);
result;
}

// @benchmark track heads
{
const list = {}, heads = [];
inputArray.forEach(item => {
  const node = list[item.dialog_node] ??= {};
  node.item = item;
  (list[item.previous_sibling] ??= heads[heads.length] = {}).next = node;
});
let head = heads.find(item => !item.item);
const result = [];
while(head = head.next) result.push(head.item);
result;
}

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Comment: This got me close. It breaks when more items are added to the list and are reordered. When 10 items are in the list, the function only returns 2 items.

Comment: @RandallRidley yes, it needs more test cases, can you add those 10 items into the question? i'll fix the code

Comment: @RandallRidley i've changed order of the existing items several times, it works. make sure you have all nodes connected, so every node would have the previous one except the first one (head)

Comment: I have updated the array. The item with the title "Q&A Contacts" is the head, but isn't the first item in the array.

Comment: @RandallRidley the list is broken, since "Feedback Capture Flow" doesn't have a next item ‍♂️

Comment: Yes, that's the last item in the list. It won't have a next sibling.

Comment: @RandallRidley couldn't figure how to get a proper head while iterating the array. Though it's possible to find it after the iteration. fixed the code. tomorrow i'll try to get the head while iterating but don't promise. anyway the solution seems working now. If it solves your problem don't forget to accept it (the grey checkbox), thanks

Comment: Looks like it's working. I accepted your code as the solution. Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

This might work

```js
function orderDialogNodes(nodes) {
  return [...nodes].sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.previous_sibling === b.dialog_node) {
      return 1
    }
    if (b.previous_sibling === a.dialog_node) {
      return -1
    }
    return 0
  });
}

const inputArray = [
 {
    type: "folder",
    dialog_node: "node_3_1702794877277",
    previous_sibling: "node_2_1702794723026",
  }, {
    type: "folder",
    dialog_node: "node_2_1702794723026",
    previous_sibling: "node_9_1702956631016",
  },
  {
    type: "folder",
    dialog_node: "node_9_1702956631016",
    previous_sibling: "node_7_1702794902054",
  },
];

const orderedArray = orderDialogNodes(inputArray);
console.log(orderedArray);
```

Comment: items could be initially sorted randomly, the sort algo could ask to compare non-sibling items too.

Answer (score -1):

Updated my answer to take into account the comment by Alexander.  I have run this numerous times with the updated data you posted and randomly ordered the data and it produces the same output each time.

This runs at an O(n^2) time complexity.

```js
const orderDialogNodes = nodes => {
  const sorted = [];

  nodes.forEach(obj => {
    if (sorted.length === 0) {
      sorted.push(obj);
      return;
    }

    for (let j = 1; j < nodes.length; j++) {
      for (let i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
        if (sorted.indexOf(nodes[j]) === -1) {
          if (sorted[i].dialog_node === nodes[j].previous_sibling) {
            sorted.splice(sorted.indexOf(sorted[i]) + 1, 0, nodes[j]);
            break;
          } else if (nodes[j].dialog_node === sorted[i].previous_sibling) {
            sorted.splice(sorted.indexOf(sorted[i]), 0, nodes[j]);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  return sorted;
};

const inputArray = [{
    type: 'folder',
    title: 'Q&A Total Rewards',
    dialog_node: 'node_2_1702794723026',
    previous_sibling: 'node_1_1702793119621',
  },
  {
    type: 'folder',
    title: 'Q&A Payroll Taxes',
    dialog_node: 'node_3_1702794877277',
    previous_sibling: 'node_2_1702794723026',
  },
  {
    type: 'folder',
    title: 'Q&A Contacts',
    dialog_node: 'node_1_1702793119621',
    previous_sibling: 'node_10_1704313850082',
  },
  {
    type: 'folder',
    title: 'Feedback Capture Flow',
    dialog_node: 'node_3_1702952290373',
    previous_sibling: 'node_76_7439096406',
  },
  {
    type: 'folder',
    title: 'Q&A Benefits',
    dialog_node: 'node_33_6664725040',
    previous_sibling: 'node_3_1702794877277',
  },
  {
    type: 'folder',
    title: 'Q&A Perf Mgmt',
    dialog_node: 'node_54_3521545375',
    previous_sibling: 'node_33_6664725040',
  },
  {
    type: 'folder',
    title: 'Q&A Workday How To',
    dialog_node: 'node_7_1702794820202',
    previous_sibling: 'node_54_3521545375',
  },
  {
    type: 'folder',
    title: 'Q&A Learning',
    dialog_node: 'node_7_1702794902054',
    previous_sibling: 'node_7_1702794820202',
  },
  {
    type: 'folder',
    title: 'Q&A Snap Levels',
    dialog_node: 'node_76_7439096406',
    previous_sibling: 'node_9_1702956631016',
  },
  {
    type: 'folder',
    title: 'Q&A Promo',
    dialog_node: 'node_9_1702956631016',
    previous_sibling: 'node_7_1702794902054',
  }
];

const orderedArray = orderDialogNodes(inputArray);
console.log(orderedArray);
```

Comment: items could be initially sorted randomly, the sort algo could ask to compare non-sibling items too, using the original indices is useless